# Investigating a function with parameters

Tags: functions

I need a little help please, I got this function: $$y=\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{k-x^2}}$$

And this function has a vertical asymptote at $x=\sqrt 5$

How do I find $k$?

Thanks :)

Comment: I edited your question by typing the formula. It is advisable to write down formulas and not post pictures unless necesary.

Comment: @5xum I have no idea how to type formulas like u do.. I use codecogs that is a latex editor. Target me where I can learn to type like u do please

Comment: You can use latex on this site! If you just click "edit" on your post, you can see how I managed to make your post look like it does.

Comment: @LiziPizi : have I answered your question? Or would you like further explanations?

Comment: @barceloco You answered it perfectly, ty

Comment: Excellent, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vertical asymptote means that $k-x^2 = 0$   for   $x=\sqrt{5}$

Hence, $k=5$.

More generally speaking:

- vertical asymptote : division by zero
- horizontal asymptote : function tends to this value for very large absolute values of $x$.

Comment: How I didn't thought about it.. thanks you very much :)

Comment: My pleasure :-)